# Java Swing GUI can't get JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I created a basis Swing UI Gui form in IntelliJ. My test.form file has a panel called "mainPanel".
When i now want to use the panel in my test.java class, i get an error, that the following exception: Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: contentPane cannot be set to null. In Debug mode i see, that the variable mainPanel is empty, but IntelliJ has the panel symbol infront of the line to show, that this is linked to the panel in the .form file.

```
public class test extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mainPanel;

    public test(){
        super("Flight Details");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        this.pack();
        this.setSize(1000, 800);


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        JFrame frame = new test();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

[screenshot of component tree with properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZXGj.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *contentPane cannot be set to null.* - that is self explanatory. Your "mainPanel" variable is null, so you can't use it to set the content pane. You need to use: `private JPanel mainPanel; = new JPanel()`. Also, note that your frame will now use a FlowLayout (not a BorderLayout) since that is the default layout manager of the JPanel.

Comment: But if i used private JPanel mainPanel; = new JPanel(), than i have a a new panel and not the panel from the text.form file

Comment: I never let the IDE generate GUI form code for me, so I'm not sure what you are talking about. I suggest you learn how to code forms yourself. That way you are learning Swing and not the IDE. Start with the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for plenty of working examples.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the Panel, but you do not initialize it.
Add the line  `mainPanel = new JPanel();` directly below the super Line. It should fix your problem. You should review the concept of declaration and initialization to avoid errors like this in the future.